# Sequence of roots of a sequence of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

For $n\geq 1$ define

$P_n(x) = x^{2n+1} - x^{n+1} - 1$

Show that $P_n$ has only one real root and the sequence of real roots converge

I can't find a root for the general case, i tried to look at critical points also but got nowhere, how can i find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is trivial to show that $P_n(x) < 0 , x \le 1$ since between $-1,1$ the $-1$ term dominates, while below $-1$ the $x^{2n+1}$ dominates; it is also trivial that $P_n$ is strictly increasing for $x \ge 1$ since the derivative is clearly positive there, while also $P_n(2) >0$ again immediately, so the (necessarily by monotonicity) unique real root satisfies $1<x_n<2$.

But now fix $a>1$ and since $a^{2n+1}-a^n-1 \to \infty$ with $n \to \infty$ it follows $P_n(a) > 0$ if $n \ge n(a)$, so $1< x_n <a, n \ge n(a)$.

Since $a>1$ arbritrary and since $x_n >1$ this proves $x_n \to 1$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*

- To prove that $P_n$ has only one real root, prove that its value at the critical points is always negative.
- To prove that the sequence of roots $z_n$ converge, prove that $P_n(1+\dfrac{1}{2n})>0$.

(caveat: conjectures suggested experimentally)

Comment: i got that its critival points are $x=0$ and $\frac{n+1}{2n+1}^{1/n}$ but it doesn't help much

Comment: why $1+1/{2n}$?

Comment: Note by Deschutes Rule of Signs that there is exactly one positive real root, and use the information about the critical points to dispose of negative real roots.

Comment: @hardmath, Deschutes? :-)

Comment: On peut avoir une chute après on a eu des cartes.